# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification_models.resnet'

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, resnet, pre-trained-model

```
from classification_models.resnet import ResNet18, preprocess_input
model = ResNet18((224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet')
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-ff8b34ae99fa> in <module>()
----> 1 from classification_models.resnet import ResNet18, preprocess_input
      2 
      3 model = ResNet18((224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification_models.resnet'
```

I am not able to import pre-trained ResNet18 model on google colab. Please help

Comment: What is the classification_models package? did you install it?

Comment: Successfully installed classification-models-0.1

Comment: I tried many other methods also, but it all fails.

Comment: from classification_models import Classifiers
classifier, preprocess_input = Classifiers.get('resnet18')
model = classifier((224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet')

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'Classifiers' from 'classification_models' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/classification_models/__init__.py)

Comment: I asked what is this package because there can be multiples with the same name, and I checked https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models and the package name and example are different from what you are using.

Comment: please guide me, how and what is the correct way to use

Comment: You are not answering my question, what exactly is the library you are using and where did you get this code from? The link I gave you has installation instructions and sample code (different from yours).

Answer (score 0):

You can access all [**ResNet**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet)`(ResNet50, ResNet101, ResNet152)` models and its `preprocess_input()` easily from `tf.keras.applications` API as below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
```

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/resnet50/ResNet50) link for more details on how to use and apply **ResNet** model.